# Showing that $\sin(1/x)$ is differentiable everywhere but $x = 0$ with the limit of the difference quotient

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$. While I know that $f'(x) = \frac{-\cos(1/x)}{x^2}$, I'd still like to revise my skills in analysis by deriving the equality with the limit of the difference quotient. The only issue is that I have no idea how to get past the initial expression $\frac{\sin(1/(x + h)) - \sin(1/x)}{h}$. Any hints/tips on the algebraic manipulation, as well as a thorough overview of the problem, are welcomed!

Comment: Honestly, the "skill" in analysis is also realizing when it's not worth working with the difference quotient. Technically speaking, you could mimic the proof of $\frac{d}{dx}\frac1x=-\frac{1}{x^2}$, the chain rule, and the proof of $\sin'=\cos$ in one single tedious calculation.

Comment: Probably writing $\frac{1}{x+h}=\frac 1x - \frac{h}{x^2} +O(h^2)$ could get you somewhere. Perhaps.

Comment: @EpsilonAway As shown in [Product-to-sum and sum-to-product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities), $\sin \theta \pm \sin \varphi =2\sin \left({\frac {\theta \pm \varphi }{2}}\right)\cos \left({\frac {\theta \mp \varphi }{2}}\right)$.